# Modifying a partial view inside of Site.Master according to user ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views, master-pages

My question is similar to this question: [access database info in a partial view, .ascx that is included in Site.Master in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521466/access-database-info-in-a-partial-view-ascx-that-is-included-in-site-master-in)

My Site.Master is not bound to a View Model or a Controller.  How can I gain access to User Context inside of a partial view which is loaded in my Site.Master file?

Comment: Can you explain it more ? What exactly is being tried to achieve ?

Comment: I suspect this is an XY problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Tell us what you are trying to do with this code, in other words the real problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I have a partial view where I need the user's asp.net id to get other information about the user.  Normally, if I am in a Controller GET method I can just call AppUserInstance.Id.  But I am not in a controller so I can not do that.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I was able to go into my Controller base class and add it to the ViewData

Answer (score 0):

You can possible use Action Filters for this purpose. In Action filters you need to override `OnActionExecuting` method and pass the UserContext in `filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.UserContext`

This dynamic viewbag you can use in your master files anywhere.

Does this answer your question?

Edit:

You need a class inheriting from `ActionFilterAttribute`
you can then ovverride its `OnActionExecuting` method like below:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
      {           
         //Your implementation here
         base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. what is filterContext