# Lock Down ASP.NET MVC App Administration Site to LocalHost only

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, authentication

I have an ASP.NET MVC website that I would like to add a small administration page to. The issue I have is that I will be deploying this all over and I will not have SSL available. I am OK with requiring the administrator to remote desktop and use the local browser to perform the administration.

Can this be done? I would basically like to get the same behavior as `<customeErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />` except for my administration pages. Can I do this via web.config some how?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Request.IsLocal` is your friend.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.islocal.aspx

You can use that to check that a request is coming from the local machine.

**Custom Attribute**

You could then extend this to be a custom attribute, but that might be overkill. If that is the route you choose this is a good example that does something similar:

[Custom Attributes on ActionResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535535/custom-attributes-on-actionresult)

MVC3 onwards allows you to set an attribute at Controller level, rather than Method too, so you could lock access to the entire controller responsible for the admin pages.

Comment: Would it be reasonable to make my own Authorize attribute that uses `Request.IsLocal` at its core?

Answer (score 9):

I did it by writing a custom attribute, like this:

```cs
public class IsLocalAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public bool ThrowSecurityException { get; set; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var isLocal = httpContext.Request.IsLocal;
        if (!isLocal && ThrowSecurityException)
            throw new SecurityException();
        return isLocal;
    }
}
```

Basic usage on an entire controller:

```cs
[IsLocal]
public class LocalOnlyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

or on a specific method:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    [IsLocal]
    public ActionResult LocalOnlyMethod()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

If you want to throw a security exception instead of a 302 redirect:

```cs
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    [IsLocal(ThrowSecurityException = true)]
    public ActionResult LocalOnlyMethod()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```